# Supervisor with ColdFusion exiting with status 1

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, supervisord

I'm attempting to let supervisord manage a ColdFusion 9 process.

I have the following in my supervisord.conf:

```
[program:coldfusion]
command=/etc/init.d/coldfusion_9
redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=unexpected               ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
```

But, when I attempt to start the supervisord service, I get the following errors:

```
2013-08-28 09:15:03,512 INFO supervisord started with pid 29417
2013-08-28 09:15:04,515 INFO spawned: 'coldfusion' with pid 29419
2013-08-28 09:15:04,526 INFO exited: coldfusion (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-08-28 09:15:05,528 INFO spawned: 'coldfusion' with pid 29423
2013-08-28 09:15:05,539 INFO exited: coldfusion (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-08-28 09:15:06,540 INFO gave up: coldfusion entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Is there any reason ColdFusion would return an exit status of 1 when being started by supervisor?

I'll see lines like this in server.log

```
"Information","main","08/27/13","10:57:15",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","Thread-1","08/27/13","10:57:25",,"ColdFusion stopped"
```

The other available logs are:

```
application.log
cfserver.log
exception.log
mail.log
```

I scoured Google, but it doesn't appear that anyone has ever attempted to manage CF with Supervisor!  -  or at least hasn't had any issues doing so.

Comment: What is being reported in the ColdFusion logs?

Comment: I found some clues in server.log (posted in question), but they don't appear to be too informative.  Is there another log that might contain better information?

Comment: look in the *instance*-out.log... for example if your instance name is cfusion it would be "cfusion-out.log" .. this will contain the standard out from Java.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't locate a _*-out.log_ file anywhere on the system. I'm using the Standard Edition on a CentOs machine, as a standalone server.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't see a mention of what CF version this is? Isn't there a `coldfusion-out.log` in the same directory as the `server.log` ? If not, maybe edit the question to include a list of the log files that _are_ there?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I adjusted the question. There is no `coldfusion-out.log ` in the `/logs` directory.   The other logs really seem redundant in as far as they contain many of the same runtime error messages, but really nothing about server status.

Comment: Well `coldfusion-out` is CF10, and I'm guessing Mark's `cfusion-out` is too (just a different config). The CF9 version is probably the `cfusion.log`, but maybe increasing the log level/verbosity will get it including the relevant information? Not sure if that's done from CF admin setting or a config file or whatever.

Comment: @user222054 - I believe we are all talking about the log files created when running ColdFusion on Windows servers. On Linux servers it behaves a bit differently. Check out these articles and see if they help (hopefully they are not outdated): [JRun 4.0 : Configuring Java stderr and stdout log files](http://helpx.adobe.com/legacy/kb/jrun-4-0-configuring-java.html) and [Configuring the Default-error and Default-out log files (Unix/Linux)](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-configuring-default-error.html)